# difference between new int[100] and new int[100]();

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, new-operator, unique-ptr

As title

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    auto* a = new float[1000000];
    auto* b = new float[10]();
    for(auto i=0; i<1000000; i++){
        std::cout << "a" << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
    for(auto i=0; i<10; i++){
        std::cout << "b" << b[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what's the difference? I had tried both output is zero.

In addition what's about smart pointer, how to make sure it can zero initialized.

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p = std::make_unique<int[]>(100);
```

Comment: One possible practical reason why uninitialized `a` contains zeros is that `new` gets zero-initialized memory from OS. For example, in Linux when you use `mmap` (and `new` can use it internally for allocation of large blocks) you get zero-initialized memory.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment: that's an explanation for your case, not a general rule. Reading uninitialized memory in C++ is Undefined Behavior. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 7):

`new int[100]` performs [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), all the elements would be initialized to indeterminate values. Note that reading from them leads to [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), anything is possible.

> - otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

`new int[100]()` performs [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), as the effect all the elements would be [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) to `0`.

> 3) if `T` is an array type, each element of the array is [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization);
>
> 4) otherwise, the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

**EDIT**

[`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) takes the 2nd way for initializing.

> 2) Constructs an array of unknown bound `T`. This overload only
>   participates in overload resolution if `T` is an array of unknown bound.
>   The function is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[size]())
> ```

PS: [`std::make_unique_for_overwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) takes the 1st way.

> 5) Same as (2), except that the array is default-initialized. This
>   overload only participates in overload resolution if `T` is an array of
>   unknown bound. The function is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[size])
> ```

Comment: Thanks, whats about the smart pointer, I had edited my original question.

Comment: @BiaoCao Answer revised.

Comment: Got it, really helpful.

Comment: And in C++20 we will have `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` for default-initialization.